# Text content does not match server-rendered HTML

Tags: reactjs, next.js, server-side-rendering, hydration

This is my code

```
<span>
  sortDate(e.createdAt)}
</span>
```

And the `sortDate` basically gives back value like 10 second ago or so on

What happens is in server the date becomes 18 sec and till it reaches client it becomes 19 sec, I think they are calling the function 2 times first in serverside then in client side. And the data mismatches and this error shows up. How do I fix this?

this sortDate function is being used in 10+ videos so don't tell useEffect -_-

Comment: Where does `e.createdAt` come from? Could you provide more code for the component where that's used. That would give more context and potentially help answer the question.

Comment: Hi there it's coming from the server, there is no solution other then sorting out the date in your backend itself. I got it working like that